# Parsing multiple json objects in java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have this json file that I'm trying to parse in my program.

```
{
  "items": [{
        "0": {
          "item_name":"Test Item",
          "item_rarity":2,
          "item_material":"STICK",
          "required_level":1,
          "min_damage":100.0,
          "max_damage":200.0,
          "item_set":"The cool kids",
          "attributes":[{"name":"lifesteal","modifier":20}]
        },
          "1": {
            "item_name":"Test Item",
            "item_rarity":2,
            "item_material":"STICK",
            "required_level":1,
            "min_damage":100.0,
            "max_damage":200.0,
            "item_set":"The cool kids",
            "attributes":[{"name":"lifesteal","modifier":20}]
        }
  }]
}
```

I am printing the JSON string, but instead of getting the individual objects (0, then 1, then 2, etc...) it only gets the whole array every time I print it out.

```
Object obj = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader(new File(ValaCraft.getInstance().getDataFolder() + "/test.json")));
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            JSONArray items = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("items");
            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                JSONObject item = (JSONObject) items.get(i);
                System.out.print(item.toString());
            }
```

Anybody have an idea on how to parse this file (without GSON, attributes is a custom class and I found it complicated to use the auto parse that gson comes with).

Comment: What is GSON anyway?

Answer (score 1):

What did you find troubling with GSON?

If you pass it to the gson.fromJSON as a JSONObject class, it should work, and you'll be able to get data from the JSON object.

```
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  JsonObject jsonFile = gson.fromJson(file.json, JsonObject.class);
```

Then you can call

```
JsonArray array = jsonFile.get("items").getAsJsonArray();
```

Then to grab the attributes from the first element of the array.

```
 array.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("attributes").getAsJsonArray();
```